# Is it possible to use client side libraries (google.visualization) on server side?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to call google.visualization or to get the result of work HtmlService without client side?

For example:
I would like to obtain the result of chart.getImageURI() ( data:image/png;base64) and insert this picture in the spreadsheet when it will be open?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the range data as `DataTable` which you then need to pass to the Charts API. I won't recommend to invoke this function when the spreadsheet is opened always. Refer the below code snippet.

```
function onOpen(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var data = ss.getRange(1, 1, ss.getLastRow(),2).getDataTable();
  var charts = Charts.newLineChart().setDataTable(data).setTitle('My Graph').setXAxisTitle("Time").setDimensions(1000, 450).build().getAs('image/png');
  ss.getRange(2, 4).clearContent(); //In order to delete the old image
  ss.insertImage(charts, 4, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, but it's not so simple.
The issue is that - I need a "newBubbleChart()" - function, which does not exist. I generate a pretty Bubble chart on client side:
var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
chart.draw(dataTable, options);
window._chart = chart;
var pngBlob = chart.getImageURI().split('data:image/png;base64,')[1] + '=';
I insert this picture in the Spreadsheet every time when the user downloads this spreadsheet (I want to have a server side event to generate a Bubble chart and insert it's picture.